# ui-grid inside ui-tabs with ng-repeater

Tags: angularjs

a simple ui-tab with ui-grid but when I change tab i need to move the page to see the table

```
 <uib-tabset class="tab-container tabbable-line">
                <uib-tab ng-repeat="user in vm.users" heading="{{user.user.fullName}}" select="vm.setTab($index)" >
                    <div id="uigrid_$index" ui-grid="{data : user.operations, 
                         columnDefs : vm.operationGridOptions.columnDefs,
                         onRegisterApi: vm.register,
                         appScopeProvider: vm}" ui-grid-resize-columns></div>
                </uib-tab>
            </uib-tabset>
```

Any Idea to resolve? or is there another way to do that?

Comment: I add a plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/KyHJ86qTZ61MABDwgn0O?p=preview to show my problme

Comment: How do I replicate the issue ? Seems fine to me

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this link http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/108_hidden_grids.

Using autoResize directive along with setting fixed widths for each column solved this problem for me.

Comment: Ok I try and have you idea how can interact from table? on registerApi on Sscope.gridone but if grid number is varible how can I solve this issue? suppose to have 10 table in 1 page and on click on 1st need to refresh 2nd or 4th

Comment: According the information you have given, After registering a grid you already store the grid apis in variables just update the grid you want. I suggest you open a new question and accept my answer if it helped.

Comment: If you can create a plunker showing your problem I can help you better !